# Magento 2.2 Drop Down to Radio button in a Product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, products

I created a **configurable product** and I set the dropdown as a selection method. How can I change it in radio buttons?
it's possible? I saw some guides on **Magento 1.9** where they set the radio buttons instead of the drop-down selection

My Magento version is 2.2.

Thanks in advanced!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input type of any attribute that is used for a product variation must be one of the following:

1. Dropdown
2. Visual Swatch
3. Text Swatch

So radio button is not supported for configurable product attribute.

Reference: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-create-configurable.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! https://ibb.co/dDvLsq  I talk about this method

Comment: @KernelPanic Yes. But that is not supported in configurable product.

Answer (score 0):

**/var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml**

getProduct();
$_attributes = $block->decorateArray($block->getAllowAttributes());
?>

isSaleable() && count($_attributes)) :?>

```
<?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute) : ?>
    <div class="field configurable required">
        <label class="label" for="attribute<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_attribute->getAttributeId()) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel()) ?></span>
        </label>
        <?php
        $attributeId=$_attribute->getAttributeId();
        ?>
        <div class="control" id="data_radio">
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            require(
                [
                    'jquery',
                    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
                ],
                function($, modal){
            var html = "";
            var attributesId = "<?php echo $attributeId ?>";
            var result = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>;
                    var repsone=result['attributes'][attributesId]['options'];
                    var optionPrices = result['optionPrices'];
                    $.each( repsone, function( key, value ) {
                        var product_prices = value.products[0];
                        var final_price = optionPrices[product_prices].finalPrice.amount;
                        html+= '<input type="radio" name="super_attribute[<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_attribute->getAttributeId()) ?>]" id="html" name="fav_language" value="'+value.id+'">';
                        html+= '<label for="html">';
                        html+= value.label+"-"+final_price;
                        html+='<label>';
                    });

                    $("#data_radio").append(html);
            });
        </script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">

    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "configurable": {
                "spConfig": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsonConfig() ?>,
                "gallerySwitchStrategy": "<?= $block->escapeJs($block->getVar(
                    'gallery_switch_strategy',
                    'Magento_ConfigurableProduct'
                ) ?: 'replace'); ?>"
            }
        },
        "*" : {
            "Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/catalog-add-to-cart": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work fairly well but any chance you'd know how to update price-box.js to account for the price getting updated when a radio is selected?